# undefined symbol st (student record system) in C

Tags: c

When I try to run the following code, it's generating an error:

> undefined symbol st

It's showing me an error on option 2 when I try to display full student records.

I'm running it on turbo C++ compiler.

```
void main()
{
    int option, i;
    while (5)
    {
    printf("========== Student Database ==========\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------\n");
    printf("1. Insert Record\n");
    printf("2. Display Record\n");
    printf("3. Edit/Update Record\n");
    printf("4. Delete a Record\n");
    printf("5. Exit\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Enter Your Choice: ");
    scanf("%d",&option);
    if(option==1)
    {
        struct student st[9];
        {
            printf("\student data");
        }
        clrscr();
        break;
    }
    else if(option==2)
    {
        printf("\n===== Displaying Student Information =====\n");
            printf("\n Roll No: \t Name \t \t \t Marks \t Mobile Number\n");
            for (i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
            {
                printf("\n %d \t %st \t \t \t %d \t %d\n", st[i].roll, st[i].name, st[i].marks, st[i].number);
            }
            clrscr();
            break;
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `1` [mcve] please. There is too much code. `2` Error on which line? Full message please.

Comment: Please don't spam tags. [tag:c] is not [tag:c++]. Also [don't tag in title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Comment: im heaving this error on line 59

printf("\n %d \t %st \t \t \t %d \t %d\n", st[i].roll, st[i].name, st[i].marks, st[i].number);

Comment: [edit] your question to add necessary information.

Comment: Also, again, [mcve] please. Too much code.

Comment: here --> https://i.imgur.com/X0vyvRi.png

Comment: Again - [edit] your question to add necessary information. Also, [mcve] please. Why don't you read my feedback comments?

Comment: Warning: If you keep asking poorly-received questions you may get a [question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

Comment: @user202729 im new here i dont know much about btw i smaller the code

Comment: No, not "smaller" that way. Please read [mcve] to understand what you are supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your declaration is in the wrong place.

```
if(option==1)
{
    struct student st[9];
    ...
}
```

This declaration is only visible inside the `if(option==1)` clause, but you try and use it inside `else if(option == 2)`

I'm guessing that you should move the declaration to the start of your program

```
void main()
{
    int option, i;
    struct student st[9];
```

You should read about a couple of concepts that are important when you use variables, *scope* which is the area of your program where the variable is visiable, and *extent* which is the time for which you variable exists. Both were wrong in the code you wrote.

There are lots of other errors in your code, but I guess you'll find out about those as you go a long.

Comment: thanks its worked but now when i entered a data then its not returing to main menu is there any code to return it to main menu after displaying or adding

Comment: @BuchiBaba That's because you put `break` and the end of your if statement. Just remove the `break`. You have to think about what the code you write actually means, you can't just add `break` because you seen it done somewhere else, you have to understand what it means in your program.

Comment: yeah i watched it on youtube. im new in coding :( its my first university project.

Comment: if i dont add break code then when i enter 5 its not exiting

Comment: @BuchiBaba Again, you need to think about what you are doing, when you do want to exit the loop then `break` is correct, when you don't then it isn't. I might be old fashioned but the way to learn programming is mainly through a good book, videos don't really do it.

Answer (score 1):

`struct student st[9];` is a local variable in the `if` blocks, that is not available in `else` block and you try to use it. Move the declaration above the `if` to make `st` array available in the both blocks.

Comment: Because this is [tag:C] that's actually correct. **edit** (better now.)

Comment: (side question: why does it count as 2 revisions while the edit is in 5 minutes of each other?)

Comment: @user202729 Thank you. OP tagged C++ and described the common linker error with the word "undefined", but really it is a compiler error "undeclared" or "not available in this scope".

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the scope of `st`. In your code the variable is only valid inside the `if` block, i.e. it's not available in the `else` block. Therefore you get a compile error.

Try this instead:

```
struct student st[9];  // Declare outside the if
if(option==1)
{
    // struct student st[9];  Don't do it inside the if
```

Answer (score 1):

`struct student st[9];` is confined to the *scope* of  `option` equal to 1, so `st` is out scope in the other parts of the `if` block, hence the compiler diagnostic.

Declare it at the start of `main`, as you do for `option`.

Lastly, think about migrating from a Turbo compiler: The standards have moved on considerably since then, and you're only getting yourself into bad habits.